# applying a window to audio samples screws the output

Tags: c, embedded, signal-processing, cmsis

Using arm_mult_f32 to multiply two arrays produces unexpected(garbage) results.

I have been reading up about dsp. I am creating Hann coefficients to apply to sampled PCM data, before the FFT.

THe hanning function is from hann.m matlab example i found, the only difference being that the stm32f4 only has a single precision FPU, so I am using uint32_t
for the data fields rather than double.

first off, the definitions.

```
FFT_LEN = 256;                   

float32_t FFTBuf[FFT_LEN * 2];   // data set twice the fft length as output 

                                 //symetrically repeated
float32_t FFTMagBuf[FFT_LEN];    //

float32_t * hann_window;
float32_t * hann_buff;
float32_t * hanning(uint32_t, uint8_t)
```

call the hanning function to populate the window.

```
hann_window = hanning(FFT_LEN * 2, 2);    // creates a dynamic array and 
                                          //populates it with coeffs.


hann_buff = (float32_t *)calloc(FFT_LEN * 2, (sizeof(float32_t)));
memset(hann_buff, 0, FFT_LEN * 2 * sizeof(float32_t));   //intermediate 
                                                         //buffer



then when all pcm samples are read

arm_mult_f32(FFTBuf, &hann_window[0], &hann_buff[0], (FFT_LEN * 2)); // 

arm_cfft_f32(&arm_cfft_sR_f32_len256, &hann_buff[0], 0, 1);

arm_cmplx_mag_f32(&hann_buff[0], FFTMagBuf, FFT_LEN);
```

The hann function is as follows

```
float32_t *hanning(uint32_t N, uint8_t itype)
  {
    uint32_t half, i, idx, n;
    float32_t *w;

    w = (float32_t *)calloc(N, sizeof(float32_t));
    memset(w, 0, N * sizeof(float32_t));

    if (itype == 1) //periodic function
      n = N - 1;
    else
      n = N;

    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
  half = n / 2;
  for (i = 0; i < half; i++) //CALC_HANNING   Calculates Hanning window samples.
    w[i] = 0.5 * (1 - cos(2 * PI * (i + 1) / (n + 1)));

  idx = half - 1;
  for (i = half; i < n; i++)
  {
    w[i] = w[idx];
    idx--;
  }
}
else
{
  half = (n + 1) / 2;
  for (i = 0; i < half; i++) //CALC_HANNING   Calculates Hanning window samples.
    w[i] = 0.5 * (1 - cos(2 * PI * (i + 1) / (n + 1)));

  idx = half - 2;
  for (i = half; i < n; i++)
  {
    w[i] = w[idx];
    idx--;
  }
}

if (itype == 1) //periodic function
{
  for (i = N - 1; i >= 1; i--)
    w[i] = w[i - 1];
  w[0] = 0.0;
}
return (w);
  }
```

With out the windowing function I get nice values, I have tested the code with
a 4khz sine wave, and it gives the correct result(without the hann window stuff)

A sample of the new output doesn't look so good.

```
{1.10114283e-019, 0 <repeats 48 times>, 35050560, inf, 0.0352631919, 
1.08468142e-019, 2.84188939e-009, inf, 143872, 142068.25, 3.31743232e+010, 
8800024, 3.29058877e+010, 0, 1.53397155e-019, 4.58692708e-013, 61631.5938, 
0, inf, 1154.63733, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, inf, 1.14477244e+011,
```

As per suggestion, removed dynamic allocation.
New ouput looks pretty, and makes sense. Will normalize input next, and continue my journey.

```
{6120297, 4445404.5, 1772673.5, 1041102.38, 659743.438, 484291.75, 
513112.688, 289598.594, 668016.812, 487091.375, 315217.875, 585517.562, 
513285.281, 268263.375, 69867.4531, 108220.406, 85955.2031, 75381.0234, 
124448.68, 559070.812, 996484.75, 1008192.25, 515462.312, 316204.938, 
124825.734,
```

Comment: Where does the memory for the `hann_window` array get allocated?  Show the code for the function `hanning()`.

Comment: thanks for taking the time kkrambo. hann function is now added. to show calloc of array memory.

Comment: arm_mult_f32(FFTBuf, &hann_window[0], &hann_buff[0], (FFT_LEN * 2)); //                   is corrected to                                                                       
    arm_mult_f32(&FFTBuf[0], &hann_window[0], &hann_buff[0], (FFT_LEN * 
     2)); //                                                                                                                 
     but still gives errant ouput.

Comment: Could it be that `calloc()` is the problem?  Did you setup a heap and is the heap large enough?  To see if `calloc()` is the problem, try using statically allocated arrays for `hann_window` and `hann_buff`.

Comment: Yes it certainly could. New output with static allocation is much more sane. Many Thanks. I will do some homework RE:Heap allocation and config as it is much new to me.Grazias kkrambo